# How to open multiple JSON file from folder and merge them in single JSON file in python?

Tags: python, json

Suppose there are 3 files - data1.json, data2.json, data3.json.

Let's say data1.json contains -

```
{ 
   "Players":[ 
      { 
         "name":"Alexis Sanchez",
         "club":"Manchester United"
      },
      { 
         "name":"Robin van Persie",
         "club":"Feyenoord"
      }
   ]
}
```

data2.json contains -

```
{ 
   "Players":[ 
      { 
         "name":"Nicolas Pepe",
         "club":"Arsenal"
      }
   ]
}
```

data3.json contains -

```
{ 
   "players":[ 
      { 
         "name":"Gonzalo Higuain",
         "club":"Napoli"
      },
      { 
         "name":"Sunil Chettri",
         "club":"Bengaluru FC"
      }
   ]
}
```

A merge of these 3 files will generate a file with the following data.
result.json -

```
{ 
   "players":[ 
      { 
         "name":"Alexis Sanchez",
         "club":"Manchester United"
      },
      { 
         "name":"Robin van Persie",
         "club":"Feyenoord"
      },
      { 
         "name":"Nicolas Pepe",
         "club":"Arsenal"
      },
      { 
         "name":"Gonzalo Higuain",
         "club":"Napoli"
      },
      { 
         "name":"Sunil Chettri",
         "club":"Bengaluru FC"
      }
   ]
}
```

How to open multiple JSON file from folder and merge them in single JSON file in python?

**My Approach :**

```
import os, json
import pandas as pd
path_to_json =  #path for all the files.
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]

jsons_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'club'])

for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
        json_text = json.load(json_file)

        name = json_text['strikers'][0]['name']
        club = json_text['strikers'][0]['club']

        jsons_data.loc[index] = [name, club]

print(jsons_data)
```

Comment: Possible solution - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87254/merging-multiple-json-files-using-python

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: The above edit -->  My approach is what I have tried.

Comment: Please take a look at the formatting, that's unreadable. Anyhow, I wonder why you use pandas at all, that just gives you additional complexity IMHO. That said, read data, process data, write data, those are the steps you need to perform and you should also try to solve these separately.

Answer (score 0):

This could to the job for you:

```py
import json
import glob
import pprint as pp #Pretty printer

combined = []
for json_file in glob.glob("*.json"): #Assuming that your json files and .py file in the same directory
    with open(json_file, "rb") as infile:
        combined.append(json.load(infile))



pp.pprint(combined)
```

Comment: Great.
Find here more on __glob__ if needed: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you wanted,

```
import json, glob

merged_json = []
for json_file in glob.glob("*json"):
    with open(json_file, "rb") as file:
      json_data = json.load(file)
      if "Players" in json_data:
        merged_json += json_data["Players"]
      else:
        merged_json += json_data["players"]

to_json = json.dumps(merged_json)
print (to_json)
```

Output

```
[{"name": "Alexis Sanchez", "club": "Manchester United"}, {"name": "Robin van Persie", "club": "Feyenoord"}, {"name": "Nicolas Pepe", "club": "Arsenal"}, {"name": "Gonzalo Higuain", "club": "Napoli"}, {"name": "Sunil Chettri", "club": "Bengaluru FC"}]
```

Comment: This answer is a slightly modified version of the answer by @Jim Erginbash. His method of reading multiple JSON files is better than what I was originally going with.